# Plot a distribution in netlogo

Tags: plot, distribution, netlogo

How to plot the distribution of patch-own variable. Let me explain the situation,
i have 5 turtles and for each patch i have calculated the difference between the closest and the farthest turtle. I want to plot this difference. Each patch will have some turtle has its closest, so I have also calculated another measure which is as follows:

```
ask patches [ set closest-party min-one-of turtles[distance myself]
                set closest-party-dist [distance myself] of closest-party
                set farthest-party max-one-of turtles[distance myself]
                set farthest-party-dist [distance myself] of farthest-party

set b (closest-party-dist - farthest-party-dist)

ask turtles [set my-size sum [b] of patches with [closest-party = myself]]
```

i want to plot the distribution of the the difference b at an overall level and for each of the turtles.

Appreciate the help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Netlogo being the best language ever has you covered if you use histogram in the plot rather than the keyword plot

```
histogram [my-size] of turtles ; if I understand you code correctly
```

will give you a histogram of turtles.

```
histogram [b] of patches
```

will give you one of the b of patches.

play with the plot options to get it the way you like. Make sure you histogram are in their own plots or in plot with other histograms in special cases never with a time plot.

**how to play with plot options**

set X min and X max to your expected range. 
the pencil icon in the plot dialog will bring up a menu. set mode to bar or point. 
set interval to the interval (bag) size you want for the bars.

Comment: Appreciate your prompt response, but i already tried what you have suggested above. The problem seems to be with the x axis range. and i am also not getting histogram bars but rather just a inverted v kind-off shape over a very small range in the x-axis. I have other plots in the interface tab where i use set-current-plot-pen. Could that cause an interference?

Comment: Gotcha I will extend my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate your help.